# CATransform3DScale Recognizer Cannot recognise

Tags: ios, scrollview, gesture, layer, catransform3d

I have a imageView on a scrollView and added a tap gesture on it  and when it is scroll the imageView will turn smaller and smaller and here the code for the transform

```
       let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    var avatarTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
    var headerTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
            let avatarScaleFactor = (min(offset_HeaderStop, offset)) / userImage.bounds.height / 1.4 // Slow down the animation
        let avatarSizeVariation = ((userImage.bounds.height * (1.0 + avatarScaleFactor)) - userImage.bounds.height) / 2.0
        avatarTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(avatarTransform, 0, avatarSizeVariation, 0)
        avatarTransform = CATransform3DScale(avatarTransform, 1.0 - avatarScaleFactor, 1.0 - avatarScaleFactor, 0)
```

I have found that  avatarTransform = CATransform3DScale(avatarTransform, 1.0 - avatarScaleFactor, 1.0 - avatarScaleFactor, 0) is affecting my recogniser if i delete this line eveything works fine.Anyone know why ?

Answer (score 0):

The scale factor on z-axis should be greater than zero; Making it zero causes the button to have "no depth", so the touches are not recognized. (Although you can still see the button)

Scaling is computed using multiplication, so in order to cause "no transformation on z-axis", the value should be `1`, rather than `0`

Change your last line to:

```
avatarTransform = CATransform3DScale(avatarTransform, 1.0 - avatarScaleFactor, 1.0 - avatarScaleFactor, 1.0)
```